# How to integrate small image into text

Tags: html, wordpress, image, format

I would like to highlight one word of text within a website with a) special font and b) small image "around" the word. Here the example:

[image]

What is the best way to realize this? So that it will work for different browsers / window sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap that word into a span. Use pseudo element with background image.

```css
body {
 background: white;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

span {
position: relative;
}

.background {
  color: red;
}

.background:before {
content:'';
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: -25px;
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
background: url(http://redhatsociety.com/sites/all/themes/red_hat_society/images/funstuff/hearts.png) no-repeat right top;
}
```

```html
 <h1>
  Everyone is <span class="background"><span class="content">special</span></span>
  </h1>
```